# ListAdapter refuses application after changing array type to int

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview, android-listfragment

After changing the array type of my list items to 'int' my list adapter refuses application of it. How can I fix this?

**ListData.java**

```
public class ListData {

    public static final String[][] items = {
            {R.string.america,R.string.america_description},
            {R.string.europe, R.string.europe_description},
    };
}
```

**within FilterListFragment.java:**

```
private void initialize(View view) {
    //Set up list view
    mAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getData(ListData.items), getActivity());
    ListView lvItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

`(ListData.items)` appears underlined in red and I get this error:

> (java.lang.string[]) in **FilterListFragment** cannot be applied to (int[][])

**ItemListadapter.java**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<String> mData;
    private List<String> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<String> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = data;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String strItem = mFilteredData.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.mDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTitle.setText(strItem);
        holder.mDescription.setText(strItem);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;
        private TextView mDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Filter for filtering list items
     */
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        /**
         * Invoked on a background thread.  This is where all the filter logic should go
         * @param constraint the constraint to filter on
         * @return the resulting list after applying the constraint
         */
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = mData;
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String str : mData) {
                    if (str.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Runs on ui thread
         * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
         * @param results the results to display
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the constructor of ItemListAdapter

Comment: your resources are int. But you have String[] which is wrong

Comment: `R.string.america` is a int resource.

Comment: I knew that but I don't know which `String`s I need to change to `int`/`Integer`

Comment: Have a look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `getData` expects a `String[]` and your are providing a matrix on `int`. You should change its signature, in order to accept an `int[][]` or better an `int[]`. If you don't want to change your adapter, let `getData`, convert the resource's id to String. E.g

```
 public List<String> getData(int[] res) {
    ArrayList<String> resStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : res) {
          resStrings.add(getString(i));
    }
    return resStrings;
 }
```

or if you want to use an `int[][]`

```
 public List<String> getData(int[][] res) {
    ArrayList<String> resStrings = new ArrayList<>();        
    for (int[] i : res) {
          for (int j : i) {
              resStrings.add(getString(j));
          }
    }
    return resStrings;
 }
```

Comment: Does this need to replace existing code in that class?

Comment: **FilterListFragment** - wasn't meant to ask that but wanna be sure

Comment: you have to change `getData`'s implementation, in `FilterListFragment`

Comment: Would this work?

`private List<String> getData(String[] res) {
        ArrayList<String> resStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i : res) {
            resStrings.add(getResource().getString(i));
        }
        return resStrings;
    }`

Comment: it will if you change `ListData.items` from `int[][]` to `int[]`, and instead of `String[] res` you have `int[] res`

Comment: I need to use `[][]` as my list items have 2 lines each. Also `(ListData.items)` in **FilterListFragment.java** appears exactly like this and doesn't have any square brackets next to it.

Comment: @MacaronLover you can use Model class and List of those class objects instead and you probably want 2 textviews or you could use one with append new line..

Comment: I edited my answer to show you, how to use the int[][]. Of course it would be way better if you used a Model class, to wrap the information you need, as suggested by @Raghunandan (thanks) . But of course, you will have to change the Adapter.

Comment: Ok, cool. Now this error appears: `Cannot resolve method getResource()`

Comment: @MacaronLover that requires a context. If in activity use `ActivityName.this` or use `getActivity()` in Fragment

Comment: you can use directly `getString()`. The method is `getResources()`, I forgot the last `s`